# Вывод родителя вместе детьми xpath в python

Tags: python, xml, xpath

С Наступившем вас и и добрый день всем!
У меня вопрос, как с помощью xpath запроса получить родителя с потомками по запросу к потомкам?
У меня есть такой код:

```
        from lxml import etree
        tree = etree.parse('out.xml')        
        nodes = tree.xpath('/osm/node')
        for node in nodes:
        print(etree.tostring(node,pretty_print=True))
        for tag in node.xpath('/osm/node/tag[@k = "name"]'):
                 print(etree.tostring(tag,pretty_print=True))
```

Запрос вроде как работает, но фрагмент `tag[@k = "name"]` не работает и я не могу понять почему и как это исправить.
Структура xml файла:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<osm version="0.6" generator="osmconvert 0.8.5">
    <node id="429459476" lat="55.6091243" lon="37.7270414" version="2" timestamp="2012-02-20T18:13:50Z" changeset="10743203" uid="210173" user="osmmaker">
        <tag k="amenity" v="library"/>
        <tag k="name" v="Детская библиотека №101"/>
        <tag k="opening_hours" v="Mo-Fr 12:00-18:00; Sa 12:00-17:00"/>
        <tag k="phone" v="+7-495-3995297"/>
    </node>
</osm>
```

Буду очень признателен вам.

Comment: А что вы пытаетесь получить? У вас тег закрывающийся, текста и вложенных тегов там не видать. Выводом должна быть пустая строка. Элементы тега можно получить так: `tag.v.text()` IIRC.